# Excel VBA Index / Match issue

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have difficulties to set up this Index/match function code.
I tried several options but it doesn't work.

I am getting the error `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`.

This is my code:

```
Sub breaks()

Dim wks As Worksheet

With Worksheets("report")
Range("I2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wks("final pos.xlsx").Sheet("position").Range("AG:AG"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("report").Range("H2"), Sheets("position").Range("AK:AK"), 0))
Range("J2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wks("final pos.xlsx").Sheet("position").Range("I:I"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("CASSreport").Range("H2"), Sheets("position").Range("AK:AK"), 0))

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what 'doesn't work' exactly? its very difficult to help when the only question is 'Can you please help me?'

Comment: First I don t get any results, only errors messages referring to the variables declarations (missing) and then to the stucure of the function.

Comment: perhaps post the error messages?

Comment: The error message is" Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: I don't think `wks("final pos.xlsx")` does what you think it does. And your error probably resides exactly here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` error then somehtng in your function is returning `Nothing` and you are attempting to use it.

the simplest way to find this is to introduce intermediary variables and then see which of them is not set. For example I have introduced temporary variables for the first part of your statement below. You can repeat for the other parts until you find the part which breaks, then see why that is not set.

```
Sub breaks()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim finalPosWorksheet as Worksheet
finalposWorksheet = wks("final pos.xlsx")

Dim position as Sheet
position = finalPosWorksheet.Sheet("position")

Dim positionRange as Range 
postionRange = position.Range("AG:AG")

With Worksheets("report")
Range("I2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(positionRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("report").Range("H2"), Sheets("position").Range("AK:AK"), 0))
Range("J2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wks("final pos.xlsx").Sheet("position").Range("I:I"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("CASSreport").Range("H2"), Sheets("position").Range("AK:AK"), 0))

End With

End Sub
```

Having written this down I'm now very dubious about the line:

```
wks("final pos.xlsx")
```

what is the intention here? To open a workbook?  I doubt this is going to work...

I'd break your code down into the steps you want to follow, with one step on each line. Once you have it working then you can refactor it to join lines together and eliminate temporary variables.

Comment: Thanks Sam. So on the "Dim position As Sheet" declaration I get a "complie error: User-defined type not defned". Can it be linked with the fact that the sheet "final position is on another workbook?

Comment: its probably that the type returned by `finalPosWorksheet.Sheet("position")` is not a `Sheet` but something else. My knowledge of the excel vba object model is not that great, so just replace `Sheet` with the actual type that `Worksheet.Sheet("blah)` returns (`WorkSheet`?)

Comment: seems it might be `Chart` as well, so might be that some other method should be used: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?512860-Worksheets-vs-Sheets